# Path and file do not exist in C# mobile

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, error-handling

I'm currently making a mobile app in Visual Studio C# Xamarin Forms and decided to use JSON for my data.

```
Workout workout = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Workout(File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/Agata/Desktop/data.json"));
```

And it couldn't find path to the JSON file and the file itself. I have checked my account status and it says that my account is administrator (well, it's only one account on PC). I have checked if my antivirus blocks the code, but it's still the same error:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path "/C:/Users/Agata/Desktop/data.json".'
```

What should I try to check and what to do to not have such error in the future?

P.S - I have tried to change slashes like this

```
Workout workout = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Workout(File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\Agata\\Desktop\\data.json"));
```

and like this

```
Workout workout = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Workout(File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/Agata/Desktop/data.json"));
```

Comment: Lol your mobile device don't have such path C:/Users/Agata/Desktop/data.json =)
Android for example have external and internal storage , so first of all you should figure out how to get path to your file on your device

Comment: Where is the file physically located?  Is it on a smart card?  Did you mount the smart card?  Did you unlock the smart card?

Comment: @DespeiL okey, thank you. I'm just new to all mobile development and using emulator for now. So for emulator it is the same like for any other device: find the path to the file, right?

Comment: Yes. After deploy your app works on the device or emulator that simulate device so you need to collaborate with mobile OS =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file path in mobile is different to PC.

**Android** groups the filesystem into two different types of storage:

- Internal Storage – this is a portion of the file system that can be
  accessed only by the application or the operating system.
- External Storage – this is a partition for the storage of files that
  is accessible by all apps, the user, and possibly other devices. On
  some devices, external storage may be removable (such as an SD card).

You can read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/) for more information about android file system.

In iOS, there are also [different Application directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#application-directories).

You can also handling files in Xamarin.Forms and here is [document and examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows).